# Can I remove block and revert it by layouts in magento2.1.4

Tags: magento, magento2

I am using magento 2.1.4. I have two themes one for desktop and another for mobile. I want to remove two blocks in desktop version only.

I have used

```
<referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>
```

to remove the block from the desktop layout

And used the below code to revert deletion in mobile theme

```
<referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="false"/>
```

But this isn't work properly is there is better solution with out any code change to do so??

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add `<referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="false"/>`

Remove this code from you mobile theme xml file. When you apply the moble theme, envirment will read current theme and then appy thw changes.

And if changes in not visible on frontend , then you need to deply again.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same situation, here is what I did fixed the issue.

In our main composer base template wishlist was removed,

```
<referenceBlock name="view.addto.wishlist" remove="true" />
```

Instead of setting remove="false" or display="true" (Which I have tried but not worked for me), I have added the below code in

> app/code/design/frontend/custom_template/default/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\View\AddTo\Wishlist" name="view.addto.wishlist.added" template="Magento_Wishlist::catalog/product/view/addto/wishlist.phtml" after="-"/> 
</referenceContainer>
```

> The Trick here is, adding a same block with different name "view.addto.wishlist.added"

Hope it helps someone.

Thanks

Kishore